# How to test onClick which programmatically fires file input

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, vitest

I'm fairly new to testing. I want to test whether my `onClick` function fired properly or not.

Behaviour of `onClick` function is firing file input programmatically.

```
const Component = () => {

  const onBtnClick = (e: SyntheticEvent) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    inputFileRef?.current?.click();
  };



  return  (
    <Box data-testid="upload-wrapper">
      <input
        data-testid="upload-input"
        type="file"
        hidden
        ref={inputFileRef}
        onChangeCapture={onFileChangeCapture}
        accept="image/jpeg,image/png,image/jpg"
        tabIndex={-1}
      />

      <Button data-testid="upload-btn" onClick={onBtnClick}>
         Upload image
      </Button>
  )

}
```

Comment: There’s a HTML-only method to do this: create a `<label>` element whose `for` attribute points to your file input element. Style the label element like a button or place a button inside of it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution from `react-dropzone` testing source file. At least it is working for my case. Here is the link [react-dropzone@src/index.spec.js](https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/blob/master/src/index.spec.js#L3371) regarding opening file dialog programmatically.

My code:

```
  it('Should open file dialog', () => {
    const onClickSpy = vi.spyOn(HTMLInputElement.prototype, 'click');

    renderScreen({});

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('image-upload-btn'));

    expect(onClickSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });


  [1]: https://github.com/react-dropzone/react-dropzone/blob/master/src/index.spec.js#L3371
```